# divs to appear below one another CSS

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want to have some content appear below my `navbar`. Right now my content and my navbar is placed on top of each other. I'm not sure which CSS property to add/change to fix this issue. I believe I am supposed to use `display: block;`. However I'm not sure where to place it

Here is a jsfiddle of an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/liondancer/69z2wepo/39146/

Here is the JSX:

```
var Logo = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    return (
    <a href="/"> Here </a>
  );
}
})

var NavBar = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="navigation">
                <div className="container">
                    <Logo/>
                    <div className="site-navigation">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/gallery">Gallery</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/news">News</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
  }
});

var Content = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="content-container">
                This is home.
            </div>
    );
  }
})

var Layout = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
    return (
       <div>
         <NavBar/>
         <Content/>
       </div>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <Layout/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.navigation {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  padding: 0 50px;
  margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
  max-width: 1400px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 45px;
}

.site-navigation {
  float: right;

 }

.site-navigation ul li{
   display: inline;
 }

.site-navigation ul li a {
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 25px;
 }

.site-navigation ul li a:hover {
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Comment: That is because your navigation class has position:absolute. 
Also you probably haven't saved your fiddle cause it contains default react fiddle.

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets thank you! Updated question

Comment: Div id, name, and class are 3 separate items within the same tag. Id and 'name' are always the same, so the DOM will function. "class" is used for text styling and position. Correct your syntax first. The location of 'display:block; will become more apparent.

Comment: @Sparky256 `id` and `name` are not always the same in html. `id` is unique, `name` is not and can be set separately from (as well as without) `id`. Plus `name` is actually invalid on most elements currently ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html)).

Comment: @abluejelly. For the old html standards that would hold true. I am just now understanding angularjs / MEAN and how it can modify or bypass the DOM, making old tag syntax obsolete. 'name' is only relevant on ancient IE browsers. My bad for thinking some were still in use.

Comment: @Sparky256 Ah yeah, the ancient IE bugs. *shudder* So glad IE 8 was EOL'd mid-January this year. That one was fixed before IE 8, but still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute;` on your `.navigation` and you will have the desired output.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/39150/)